# SQL using two tables to create a binary correlation table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Okay this one is a doozy, I am trying to manipulate my data in sqlite and am still quite new, any help appreciated! Here is what the data looks like (a couple of different screenshots):

**Screenshot of Table1, section showing Germany**

[image]

**Screenshot of Table1, section showing USA**

[image]

**Screenshot of Table2**

[image]

Ultimately, I want to return a table with Germany and USA as columns (found in Table 1 "country_A" column) and every other country as the rows (found in the Table2 "country" column). The values would be either 1 or 0 if there is a match between the two tables.

As an approximate example of what I am looking for:

```
country         USA     Germany
Afghanistan     0         1
Albania         1         1      
Algeria         0         1 
  etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the tables and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t2.country,
       COALESCE(MAX(t1.country_A = 'USA'), 0) USA,
       COALESCE(MAX(t1.country_A = 'Germany'), 0) Germany
FROM Table2 t2 LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
ON t1.country_B = t2.country AND t1.country_A IN ('Germany', 'USA')
GROUP BY t2.country
```

Or without a join and aggregation, with EXISTS which sometimes performs better:

```
SELECT t2.country,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.country_A = 'USA' AND t1.country_B = t2.country) USA,
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t1 WHERE t1.country_A = 'Germany' AND t1.country_B = t2.country) Germany
FROM Table2 t2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT t2.country,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE country_A = 'Germany' and country_B = t2.country) AS Germany,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1 WHERE country_A = 'USA' and country_B = t2.country) AS USA
FROM t2;
```

Another (better) way to do it:

```
  SELECT t2.country, 
         COUNT(CASE t1.country_A WHEN 'Germany' THEN 1 END) as Germany,
         COUNT(CASE t1.country_A WHEN 'USA' THEN 1 END) as USA
    FROM t2
    JOIN t1 
      ON country_b = t2.country
GROUP BY t2.country;
```